# Fetch Blogger Posts based on Order

Tags: php, google-api, blogger

I am fetching data using blogger post API.

> https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/blogId/posts

The results are coming in the **newest to oldest** format with pagination.I need to fetch with **oldest to newest** because i need the newest post's time to fetch the data in the next call for the new posts.

How can I use the API with parameters.Currently, i am using the following api call

`https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/posts?startDate2015-10-15T00:00:00+00:00&key=$key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Posts: list](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/list) only supports ordering by published or updated, not the direction.

> orderBy   string  Sort order applied to results.
>
> - Acceptable values are: "published": Order by the date the post was
> - published "updated": Order by the date the post was last updated

I would recommend you sort them yourself after you get the results back from Google.

Comment: no the API does not support the direction of the sort you need to do that

Comment: I am using startDate parameter. On the above mentioned api call, I am getting the posts from 2015-10-15. But i am getting the post created at 2012-03-06. Can you give me the example for using correct date format.

Comment: @karthick that sounds like it should be a new questions.